# Tengo que iterar sobre un objeto anidado aplicando recursión en js pero no me sale

Tags: javascript

```
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      },
    }
}

var objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
    if(obj[prop] === value) {
      return true
    }else if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object'){
      return function(obj[prop], prop, value)
    }
  }
```

Caso que devuelve true  --> `objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield");`

Caso que devuelve false --> `objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mucho me temo que al declarar la función como variable, no se va a poder hacer la recursión, supongo que no acaba de realizarse la asignación cuando quieres ejecutar nuevamente y devuelve `undefined`, por lo que debes crear la función de la forma clásica.

Lo que puedes intentar es:

1. Verificar que el valor recibido es un objeto, de lo contrario, vas a obtener errores
2. Analizar si el objeto tiene la propiedad buscada con [.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) y, de ser el caso, devolver verdadero o falso, dependiendo del valor
3. Como es un objeto, es necesario obtener las propiedades y recorrer dentro de un ciclo
4. En el ciclo, si la propiedad es un objeto, haces la recursión
5. Solo si se encontró el valor, devuelves verdadero
6. Al final de la función se devuelve falso porque:

   - prop no era un objeto
   - No tenía la propiedad buscada
   - En el ciclo tampoco se encontró esa propiedad o el valor no coincide con el buscado

```js
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      }
    }
};
// La función debe ser "normal" por nombre
function objContains(obj, prop, value) {
    // ¿Es objeto?
    if(typeof obj == 'object') {
        // Verifica que tiene la propiedad buscada
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // Sí existe, devolver si el valor (y tipo) es igual al buscado
            return (obj[prop] === value);
        }
        // Obtener propiedades
        let keys = Object.keys(obj);
        // Recorrer
        for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            // Recursividad solo si es objeto
            if(typeof obj[keys[i]] == 'object' && objContains(obj[keys[i]], prop, value)) {
                // Se encontró el valor buscado
                return true;
            }
            // Si no se encontró, seguir con el ciclo
        }
        // No se encontró el valor al salir del ciclo
        // Al final de la función se devuelve falso
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield"));
console.log(objContains(user, "nombre", "Homero Simpson"));
console.log(objContains(user, "direccion", "Falso, la propiedad es un objeto, no cadena"));
console.log(objContains(user, "estado", "Falso, es diferente"));
console.log(objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby !!

Answer (score 1):

Si bien este no se ve como el mejor código del mundo ni mucho menos, la idea que tuve al realizar este código fue no solo preservar la estructura que ya poseias, si no que ademas funcionara y se extendiera su funcionamiento.

La cosa es que el codigo que poseias tenia algunos errores, uno de ellos es que estabas tratando de retornar una nueva función la cual de por si ya se encontraba mal construida, esto por supuesto generaba errores, si quisieramos corregir eso para que almenos funcione el código, se veria asi:

```js
var objContains = function(obj, prop, value) {
  if (obj[prop] === value) {
    return true
  } else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
    //this es un puntero, y se refiere al contexto actual, en este caso nuestra función
    //Podemos ejecutar nuestra función llamandola con this
    return this(obj[prop], prop, value)
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, el codigo que poseias, tiene un problema, y es que solo estarias buscando coincidencias en el primer nivel del objeto y con suerte en el segundo nivel del objeto (si llega a existir), ya que no estas iterando el objeto para ir buscando dentro de las propiedades del objeto.

Por lo que propongo el siguiente código, en el cual dentro de el se explica que es lo que se hace.

```js
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      },
    }
}

var objContains = function(obj, prop, value, index = 0){
    //Para no realizar demasiadas iteraciones miramos primero si
    //En el objeto o sub-objeto existe la propiedad buscada, si existe miramos si
    //El objeto en esa propiedad posee nuestro valor, de ser asi entonces
    //directamente lo retornamos
    if(prop in obj){
      if(obj[prop] === value){
        return true;
      }
    }

    //Obtenemos solo las keys del objeto en un array
    const keys = Object.keys(obj).slice(index);
    
    //Recorremos las propiedades con un for a fin de no desperdiciar memoria
    //Y para hacer mas eficiente el proceso
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
      //Valor actual del objeto en una de sus keys
      const curr = obj[keys[i]];
    
      //Retorna true si el valor es encontrado con la clave proporcionada
      if(curr === value) {
        return true
      }else if(typeof curr === 'object'){
        //Retornamos la operacion de realizar una recursion del sub-objeto,
        //A la vez, aprovechamos de que si la operacion en el sub-objeto devuelve
        //false, entonces seguimos recorriendo las demas propiedades del
        //Objeto principal hasta encontrar una coincidencia
        return objContains(curr, prop, value, 0) ||
               objContains(obj, prop, value, ++index);
      }else{
        //Seguimos con la recursion del objeto actual en caso de que
        //el valor no coincida y que ademas el valor no sea del tipo objeto
        return objContains(obj, prop, value, ++index);
      }
    }
    
    //Si al hacer todo el proceso de recursion aun asi no se encuentra el valor
    //Entonces damos por sentado de que el valor buscado con su propiedad no existe
    return false;
}

console.log(objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield"));
console.log(objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear"));
```

Notese que las dos ideas principales del código son limitar la recursion para conseguir performance, y ademas que se busque en el objeto cumpleto y en sus sub-objetos (paramos en la primera coincidencia completa), donde la `key` y el `valor`buscado deben coincidir para ser retornados.

El hecho de que se busque en el objeto completo y en sus sub objetos quizás llegaria a consumir mas memoria y tiempo debido a que busca en todo el objeto la primera coincidencia, sin embargo esto permite que el ciclo principal del objeto no pare en caso de que no encuentre alguna coincidencia en el primer subobjeto, resolviendo el problema de que quizas sí haya una coincidencia, pero ésta no sea tomada en cuenta por no ser el primer objeto evaluado.

Comment: A mi respuesta añadele que la forma correcta o mas adecuada de mirar si una propiedad existe en un objeto es la que usa @Triby, con `object.hasOwnProperty` y no usando el operador `in`, ya que al ser propiedades customizadas estariamos apuntando a cualquier propiedad que exista en el objeto con ese nombre, y no las que fueron descritas propiamente en el objeto.

Comment: De todas maneras dejo en la respuesta el operador `in`, mas que todo para dejar un ejemplo de su uso, pero ya queda aclarado que lo que deberia usarse es `object.hasOwnProperty`, como lo ha hecho triby en su respuesta. El operador `in`, es usado mas que todo cuando se necesita saber si una propiedad o metodo de un objeto nativo en la pagina esta disponible o no, por ej `getUserMedia` en el objeto `navigator`.

Comment: Como siempre, una excelente respuesta, con muy buenos fundamentos y mejores explicaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro!

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de recorrer un *Object* es usando el método [`parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) de JSON, primero convirtiendo el object en cadena con el metodo stringify de JSON, así:

```js
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      }
    }
}

function objContains(prop, value) {      
    string = JSON.stringify(user)    
  let response = false    
  JSON.parse(string, (p, val) => { if (prop === p && value === val) response = true })    
  return response
}

console.log( objContains( "barrio", "vuvu" ))
console.log( objContains( "barrio", "Springfield" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé porque las respuestas anteriores se han complicado tanto

Creo que la respuesta más simple es esta:

```
const objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
  if(typeof obj[prop] !== 'object' && obj[prop] === value) {
    return true;
  }
  return Object.values(obj).some( a => typeof a == 'object' && objContains(a,prop,value));
}
```

Usamos [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para recorrer el array de valores entregado por `Object.values` y preguntamos ¿Es un objeto? que viene a ser la condición de parada para que no siga iterando al infinito, y si es un objeto ejecuta la función de manera recursiva

Demo:

```js
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      },
    }
}

const objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
  if(typeof obj[prop] !== 'object' && obj[prop] === value) {
    return true;
  }
  return Object.values(obj).some( a => typeof a == 'object' && objContains(a,prop,value));
}
  
console.log(objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield"));
console.log(objContains(user, "nombre", "Homero Simpson"));
console.log(objContains(user, "direccion", "Falso, la propiedad es un objeto, no cadena"));
console.log(objContains(user, "estado", "Falso, es diferente"));
console.log(objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear"))
```

Nota: Incluso sin el uso de `some` se puede usar la misma lógica empleando un `for`, que a mi parecer sigue siendo menos enredado que las soluciones anteriores

```
const objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
  if(typeof obj[prop] !== 'object' && obj[prop] === value) {
    return true;
  }
  let resp=false
  for(let a of Object.values(obj)){
       resp = typeof a == 'object' && objContains(a,prop,value)
  }
  return resp;
}
```